# What is the use of Lady of the Lake card in avalon?

Tags: the-resistance, the-resistance-avalon

I have always wondered what is the use of this card. It would be great if someone could help me out with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is to enable players to get more information about each other out in the open. If it starts out on a good player they can use it to help identify other good players. On the other hand if it starts in a bad players hand they can use it to cause confusion.

https://www.ultraboardgames.com/avalon/optional-rules.php

> This token is an optional player ability. The player with the Lady of the Lake will be able to look at the loyalty of another player. Unlike the other character powers, the player that has this ability is open information.
>
> At the beginning of the game, give the Lady of the Lake token to the player on the Leader's right.
>
> Immediately after the 2nd, 3rd and 4th Quest is resolved, the player with the Lady of the Lake token will choose one player to examine. The player being examined will receive a pair of Loyalty cards and pass the card that corresponds to the loyalty of ther character card to the Lady of the Lake. Using the wrong loyalty card will result in losing the game.
>
> The lady of the Lake may discuss, but cannot reveal the Loyalty card passed.
>
> The player being examined receives the Lady of the Lake token. The Lady of the Lake will only be used three times in the game. A player that used the Lady of the Lake cannot have the Lady used on them.
> Note: the Lady of the Lake is best saved for games of 7 or more people. Adding the Lady of the Lake into a game will make the Good side more powerful and win more often.